# Restrict sorting based on some condition in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have gridview in my application and I need to restrict sorting if either of the 2 buttons- Button A and Button B is clicked.

I am using hidden field for the same and on the click event of both the buttons i am giving the value of hidden variable as 1.

When sort event is called, i am checking that if hiddenfield value is not equal to 1, then sorting should be perform.

But when i debug, i see the hidden field has lost its value & is coming null.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom solution for this, you can just programatically set the [GridView.AllowSorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting.aspx)-Property.

The problem about the disappearing value most probably has to do with the Postback. If you do not use ViewState or store the value manually between Postbacks, it gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

other than that: did you try setting the hiddenfield to runat="server" and EnableViewState="true" ?